# circular dependency between NX libraries when defining entities

Tags: graphql, nestjs, circular-dependency, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have some architectural questions about NX libraries in my app with the following stack: NestJS/GraphQL/TypeORM.

Let's say I want to build an expense management app with multiple entities like "expense", "credit card", "wallet", "customer", ״company״, etc... where all entities are deeply related
(expense is made from a card, which belongs to a wallet, which is owned by a user, which works at a company, etc...)

I plan to create an NX library for each entity - containing the entity file (for example expense.entity.ts), repository, graphqlObject, and also multiple use cases.

The problem is that due to the relations, I׳m going to have a circular dependency between all of those libraries, no matter if it's in the entity file, the graphql object file, or perhaps some of the use-cases of one entity require using a repository of another, etc...

In addition to the circular dependency issues, this kind of design will cause NX to rebuild almost every library no matter what file changes...

What will be the correct thing to do here?

Comment: Recommend the feature, data-access, ui, util library 80:20 approach from *Enterprise Angular Applications* (free ebook). Let the Nx structure be driven by *app features*. If multiple app features need to share app feature specific data-access libs then pull these into a shared libraries. It's cheap to refactor libraries in Nx imo so I wouldn't optimise early

Comment: @Tal - Did you ever figure this out? We have a similar situation. Think entities Posts, Tags, and PostTags. How can library `post/models` with post.model (with tags property) reference `tags/models` with tag.model and post-tag.model (with post property). They all need to depend on each other!